I wasn't able to console or get the visible text from a ui for a customer Id which will be unique for each customercreation in playwright
I have a span element in the dom structure
<span data-template data-test-id="20150102041453079138117" class>1209043473</span>

I tried every method like textContent(), innerText(), innerHTML(), etc but couldn't get the visible text
Getting timeout error:

locator.innerText: timeout 50000ms exceeded
waiting for locator('span[data-test-id="20150102041453079138117"]')

Need to get the visible text from the attribute
i need the console output as 1209043473

page.loccator('span[data-test-id="20150102041453079138117"]') works fine on this HTML element. Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] with the actual site--there is likely some site-specific behavior that accounts for the failure, like a random id, cloudflare block, iframe, arbitrary JS timing, etc. Thanks.
